# Accessing the Area name from a shared Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a shared `_Layout.cshtml` file that is used by views in separate Areas.

The `_Layout.cshtml` has an `@Html.Action` call to an Action on a Controller in the 'root' Area (not sure how to refer to the none-area Area) that returns a `PartialViewResult`.

My question is can I access the name of the area that's being accessed from the Partial action?

So, if a user accesses `/Users/User/Create`, the Create view in the Users Area uses the common `_Layout.cshtml` which calls the common Controller Action.  I need to be able to get at "Users" in that method.

So far I've looked in the `ParentActionViewContext.RouteData` but only the controller and action names show up in there (as I would expect).

Answer (score 0):

Based on [our brief Twitter conversation](https://twitter.com/davidgouge/status/365188607759220736), you say that you're doing this to highlight the current area in a menu/nav-bar.

I've done something similar in the past where I've treated the menu as a partial view with its own controller and action. Taking that approach would allow you to expose on your (view-)model for a `MenuItem` a bool for "selected" or "active" and then use a custom HTML Helper to write out the appropriate HTML for an active/inactive menu item.

Off topic, I know, but it's possible you may have made your areas too fine-grained. For example, what other controllers beyond the `UserController` does the Users area contain? Could you perhaps use separate controllers in the default area to achieve the same separation of functionality?

Comment: I think you're right about being too fine-grained.  At least at the moment.  I think it's a good case of YAGNI. :)